# DB2 Stored Procedure try catch

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Hi i'm creating a database with DB2. I use IBM Data Client. I want to use try catch into my stored procedure but it seems that are not supported by DB2, can any one help me? I need to handle sql errors and to return its. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Applicazione_Aggiorna
(               
                IN @VAR1 INT,
                IN @VAR2 INT,
                IN @VAR3 VARCHAR(16),
                OUT @RETURNCODE INTEGER
)

LANGUAGE SQL
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND
SET @RETURNCODE = SQLCODE;



IF not exists (select VAR1 from DB.TABLEA where VAR1 = @VAR1)
THEN
    set @ReturnCode = 3011;
ELSE
    UPDATE          DB.TABLEA SET
                    VAR2=@VAR2,
                    VAR3=@VAR3
    WHERE VAR1=@VAR1;
                    
END IF;
END P1
```

Answer (score 1):

DB2 LUW supports exception handlers (continue handlers, or exit handlers) for SQL PL procedures. Look in the DB2 Knowledge Center for your version for all the details.  You can use them alongside conditions. You can have multiple handlers if you need specific processing. There are plenty of sample SQL PL procedures in both the Knowledge Center and in the DB2 LUW installed product directories.

Comment: Yeah i've already seen it. It says that i've to use the sqlstatuscode that is a special variabile for error handling that has to assigned to tour returncode variabile but it does not work this is the reason of my answer. I seen the sample code but does not work for me. i assign the sqlstatuscode to my retcode variable and even if i have an errore the retcode is always 0. I intentionally try to assign values that violate a foreign key constraint into my procedure but the retcode value does not change. Db2 does not inserti the value but i cant handle the error

Comment: Post your code and detail your tool chain in full.  DB2 sets the SQLCODE variable when dml/ddl runs in your SQL PL procs and exception handlers (for continue, or for error) do work correctly when you understand how to use them.

Comment: It is DB2 that raises (invokes) the exception and calls your handler, only the DB2 itself finds the error. If you manually set the SQLCODE then DB2 will not react (it will overwrite its value at the next DML/DDL execute time). A default exit-handler exists for exceptions also.