# SQL to IBMDB2 syntax issue

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, db2-luw

I am trying to execute the following SQL script inside a IBMDB2- however unable to get the syntactically correct script for IBMDB2;

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    if not exists (select * from AAA.BBBB WHERE COL1='[Param.1]' and COL2=[Param.2] and COL3='[Param.3]')
    begin
        INSERT INTO PRODFILE.MESUPPF (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4,  COL5, COL6)
        VALUES( '[Param.1]', [Param.2], '[Param.3]', '[Param.4]' , '[Param.5]', '[Param.6]' )
    end
    else
    begin
        update AA.BB set COL1='[Param.4]',COL2='[Param.5]',COL3='[Param.6]'  WHERE COL4='[Param.1]' and COL5=[Param.2] and COL6='[Param.3]')
    end
    Select  'Success'  as Message, 'S' as MessageType

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG (LOGTM,LOGTX) VALUES (getdate(),CAST(ERROR_LINE()AS VARCHAR(4)) + ERROR_MESSAGE())
    Select  'Error'  as Message, 'E' as MessageType

END CATCH
```

Comment: Db2 uses SQL. Do you mean an SQL script written for another database system?

Comment: @data_henrik no! Actually I am trying to execute the above sql script in an DB2 (AS400) system- however the above sql script doesn't execute. It gives errors pertaining to usage of TRY,IF etc. However the above same script WORKS FINE IN SQL SERVER

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2 Stored Procedure try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618543/db2-stored-procedure-try-catch)

Comment: Did you try searching the internet for "db2 error handling"?

Comment: What flavor of DB2 are you talking about? DB2 for zOS (mainframe), DB2 for i (midrange), DB2 for LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows)? They are slightly different, and the correct documentation link will depend on the flavor you are using.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy client is using IBMDB2 on windows

Comment: @Rajeev Ok, but the client is not what determines the dialect. The server determines that. I am now guessing that the DB2 server is located on Windows and you just misspoke when you said client.

Comment: Here is the [DB2 for LUW documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.welcome.doc/doc/welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

DB2 for IBM i doesn't allow execution of compound sql statements outside of SQL routines.
Refer to [CREATE PROCEDURE (SQL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcrtpsf.htm) on how to create such a routine with DB2 dialect of statements inside.

Comment: Does this hold for DB2 LUW

Comment: @jmarkmurphy If the question is on if Db2 for LUW has the same limitation, then the answer is: no. Db2for LUW does allow compound statements. But the SQL syntax is different from SQL Server, of course. [Compound SQL (compiled) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html)